# How can I prevent last item of the ListBox get selected when empty area is clicked

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

I have a list box which is not filled with items all the way down, and has some empty area after last item. When I click that empty area the last item is automatically get's selected. And that selection happens before `MouseDown` event. And I want to prevet it from happening.

I can keep current selected index (only one item can be selected) in a variable in `SelectedIndexChanged`, and reset it in `MouseDown`, but between `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` last item is selected - and it doesn't look good.

How can I prevent last item from being selected when empty area is clicked?

---

*P.S. This is owner-drawn ListBox, but I'm not sure it has anything to do with this issue.*

```
private void listBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightSteelBlue, e.Bounds);
    }
    else
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, e.Bounds);
    }

    if (_commands.Count > 0)
    {
        KeyValuePair<string, string> cmd = (KeyValuePair<string, string>)_commands[e.Index];

        // FIRST ROW
        e.Graphics.DrawString(cmd.Key, _cmdNameFont, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y + _cellPadding);

        // SECOND ROW
        e.Graphics.DrawString(cmd.Value,
            _cmdCommandFont, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.X + 5, e.Bounds.Y + _cmdNameFont.Height + _cellPadding);
    }

    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}

private void listBox_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.ItemHeight = _cmdNameFont.Height + _cmdCommandFont.Height + _cellPadding * 2 ;
}
```

Comment: Strange, my colleague is having the same problem with her owner-drawn listbox: clicking the empty space selects the last item.

Answer (score 1):

I have a work around. You can place a panel and dynamically change its height based on the screen height,listbox height. In that case when you click the empty area, the new panel takes the click.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by inspecting the mouse down message and not letting it process the message if the user isn't clicking on an item:

```
public class ListBoxEx : ListBox {
  private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;

  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    int lParam = m.LParam.ToInt32();
    int wParam = m.WParam.ToInt32();
    if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN) {
      Point clickedPt = new Point();
      clickedPt.X = lParam & 0x0000FFFF;
      clickedPt.Y = lParam >> 16;
      bool lineOK = false;
      for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++) {
        if (GetItemRectangle(i).Contains(clickedPt)) {
          lineOK = true;
        }
      }
      if (!lineOK) {
        return;
      }        
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
  }
}
```

Posted this from my answer at [OwnerDrawVariable ListBox selects last item when clicking on control below items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48387671/719186)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are returning the right value from OnMeasureItem.

---

EDIT:  Appears to be a difference in how OwnerDrawVariable works.
Normally, IndexFromPoint (the hit test) returns -1 if empty space is clicked. 
With OwnerDrawVariable, it returns the bottom item.

You have two choices.

1)  Your items are all the same height so you can use OwnerDrawFixed and your problem goes away.

```
base.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
this.ItemHeight = this.Font.Height + this.Font.Height + _cellPadding * 2;
```

2) Handle the mouse click at a lower level and throw out the empty-space one.

Comment: thnx for reply. in `MeasureItem` i only calculate `e.ItemHeight`. if i start changing that value, the rows look messed up. all rows are of the same height.

Comment: Are you sure the item is being selected, and not just getting the focus box drawn around it?

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(listBox.SelectedIndex.ToString());` in `MouseDown` return index of the last item (and the item is drawn selected too) when I click empty area. but the first item was selected before the click.

Comment: When I place that message box in `SelectedIndexChanged` and click empty area - the last item gets painted when I press mouse button, and i get the pop-up (with index of last item) when i let go of mouse button

Comment: It must be connected to the DrawMode then.  A quick test app with Normal DrawMode and just a ListBox on the form doesn't behave that way.  The selected item stays selected, and the last item gets the focus box (which can be 'fixed' by setting the focus to another control on the ListBox Click).