# OwnerDrawVariable ListBox selects last item when clicking on control below items

Tags: winforms

I noticed this problem in a ListBox in my application, and then determined that the example given on MSDN for ListBox.MeasureItem suffers from the same problem.

When you set a ListBox's DrawMode to OwnerDrawVariable in order to handle the MeasureItem event ( say to draw the list items with an increased height ), the control will select the last item if you click on the empty region below the last item.

I would like it to behave the way it does when DrawMode is set to OwnerDrawFixed or Normal, and not change the item selection if the user clicks on the control below the list of items.

I tried to achieve this behavior by handling the MouseDown event and found that the control selects the bottommost item before it fires the MouseDown event.

I wonder if I need to subclass ListBox, or if there is a better way to do this.

In order to see the behavior, the code sample from MSDN suffices:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.measureitem(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is built-in behavior down in the Win32 control.  Essentially, when you click the ListBox, a method called `IndexFromPoint` (you can call this yourself via the control instance) is called to determine the index of the selected item.

I tried taking full control over the process, but I couldn't find any evidence that even then you can tell the difference between clicking on an actual item or not when the control is using `DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable`.

As such, it is my belief that you cannot control it.  But you might dodge it:

```
private void ListBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    for (Int32 i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        var rect = ListBox1.GetItemRectangle(i);
        if (rect.Contains(e.Location))
            return;
    }
    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

As you noticed, the item will already be selected by the time this event fires.  This simply tries to un-select it fast enough to not be noticeable.  If the ListBox has a lot of items in it, you might notice it as a flicker.

This is probably the best you could do.

Comment: Thank you! This will do the trick for me. This is rather clever, to just try to undo the undesirable behavior. I was trying to _prevent_ it, and that didn't go so great for the reasons you stated - behavior appears to be baked into the control. I tried this out and it works nicely enough!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by inspecting the mouse down message and not letting it process the message if the user isn't clicking on an item:

```
public class ListBoxEx : ListBox {
  private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;

  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    int lParam = m.LParam.ToInt32();
    int wParam = m.WParam.ToInt32();
    if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN) {
      Point clickedPt = new Point();
      clickedPt.X = lParam & 0x0000FFFF;
      clickedPt.Y = lParam >> 16;
      bool lineOK = false;
      for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++) {
        if (GetItemRectangle(i).Contains(clickedPt)) {
          lineOK = true;
        }
      }
      if (!lineOK) {
        return;
      }        
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
  }
}
```

Comment: This would be a more solid way to get this behavior consistent across a whole application - create a user control like this to use instead of the standard Listbox. Very nice!

Comment: Preferable approach if you want a `ListBox` that you can drop onto a form with this behavior "straight out of the box".